# How do I not take Special Characters in my Password Validation (without Regex)?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am a beginner to Java and currently I have code that looks something like this.

The rules are: no special characters, only lowercase or numbers from 0 to 9.

This code is working fine, but it also takes special characters. Are there any other ways to stop that from happening? **No Regex please**.

```java
if (Password.length() >= 10 && Password.equals(Password.toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println("Password: Success");
} else {
    System.out.println("Password: Unsuccessful");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method to get a stream over `int` values of characters of this string and [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count()) quantity of them before first occurrence of *non-lowercase* and *non-digit* character. Your code might look something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isLowerCaseOrDigits("EqwerJ")); // false
    System.out.println(isLowerCaseOrDigits("as56re")); // true
    System.out.println(isLowerCaseOrDigits("vb3451")); // true
    System.out.println(isLowerCaseOrDigits("827136")); // true
    System.out.println(isLowerCaseOrDigits("8271)&")); // false
}
```

```java
private static boolean isLowerCaseOrDigits(String str) {
    return str.codePoints()
            .takeWhile(ch -> Character.isLowerCase(ch)
                    || Character.isDigit(ch))
            .count() == str.length();
}
```

---

Or without `stream`, you can use [`String.toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) method and iterate over the array of characters of this string. Return `false` on the first occurrence of *non-lowercase* and *non-digit* character:

```java
private static boolean isLowerCaseOrDigits(String str) {
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isLowerCase(ch) && !Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) method:

```java
private static boolean isLowerCaseOrDigits(String str) {
    return str.codePoints().allMatch(ch ->
            Character.isLowerCase(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch));
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean[] arr = {
            isLowerCaseOrDigits("EqwerJ"),
            isLowerCaseOrDigits("as56re"),
            isLowerCaseOrDigits("vb3451"),
            isLowerCaseOrDigits("827136"),
            isLowerCaseOrDigits("8271)&")};

    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::println);
    // false
    // true
    // true
    // true
    // false
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Difference between anyMatch and findAny in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890667/14940971)</sup>